# Android Studio - java.lang.StackOverflowError at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated - Completely bamboozled

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow, viewgroup

I am completely at a loss, I am getting a StackOverflowError when trying to go from one fragment to another. This has worked in the past without issues and none of the recent changes I have made should have any effect on this functionality. I am using a different version of Android Studio but this functionality has worked since the upgrade. I also don't see how that could be relevant, but I'm trying to look for any variables at this point.

It looks like it is trying to call a ViewGroup but it is caught in a recursive loop with ViewOverlay? I've gone through my own code and see no such recursion on my end. And it's not like I'm trying to load anything particularly large, just 12 or so recycler items in a basic recycler using a basic recycler adapter.

The reported logcat:

```
18:06:14.655  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.package.app, PID: 3136
                 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
18:06:14.660  E     at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
18:06:14.940  I  uid=10121(com.package.app,) identical 2499 lines
18:06:14.940  E     at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
18:06:14.940  E     at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewOverlay.java:339)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onDescendantInvalidated(ViewGroup.java:6024)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:6042)
                    at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:18528)
                    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:18458)
                    at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:23091)
18:06:14.940  E     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateDrawable(TextView.java:7722)
                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:477)
                    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.invalidateSelf(RippleDrawable.java:690)
                    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.cancelExitingRipples(RippleDrawable.java:239)
                    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.jumpToCurrentState(RippleDrawable.java:223)
                    at android.view.View.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(View.java:23602)
                    at android.widget.TextView.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(TextView.java:7656)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:7585)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:7585)
                    at android.view.View.onAttachedToWindow(View.java:19945)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.onAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:5157)
                    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
                    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20457)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5278)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4976)
                    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.add(ViewOverlay.java:208)
                    at android.view.ViewGroupOverlay.add(ViewGroupOverlay.java:72)
                    at android.transition.Visibility.onDisappear(Visibility.java:450)
                    at android.transition.Visibility.createAnimator(Visibility.java:255)
                    at android.transition.Transition.createAnimators(Transition.java:733)
                    at android.transition.TransitionSet.createAnimators(TransitionSet.java:444)
                    at android.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1777)
                    at android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:327)
                    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1093)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3089)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
18:06:15.132  I  Sending signal. PID: 3136 SIG: 9
```